# Does the Dash action double all modes of movement, or just footspeed?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, flight

I know this question is probably stupid, but I couldn't find anything for either side. I don't think it's in one of the books that D&D Beyond provides for free.  I could also just be blind and not see it.

I'm mainly talking about flight speed and burrow speed, whether it's granted by a spell or by a race: would using the Dash action double flight speed or burrow speed (or swimming speed) given that you have a non-zero number in them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Dash action does not mention any particular mode, so it applies to each of your speeds.

The Dash Action description states:

> When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers. With a speed of 30 feet, for example, you can move up to 60 feet on your turn if you dash.
>
> Any increase or decrease to your speed changes this additional movement by the same amount. If your speed of 30 feet is reduced to 15 feet, for instance, you can move up to 30 feet this turn if you dash.

Walking, flying, burrowing, swimming or any other speed are not mentioned anywhere in this description, so it applies to all types of movement in the same way.

Comment: Does the same apply to a set amount of movement granted by spells such as fly?

Comment: @Tasi Yes, see [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/195889/62294)

Comment: Another movement speed is crawling.